# How to calculate the sum of $\sum\limits_{j}{\langle A|{{B}_{j}}\rangle |{{C}_{j}}\rangle }$ with quantum circuits?

Tags: qiskit, textbook-and-exercises

How to calculate the sum of $\sum\limits_{j}{\langle A|{{B}_{j}}\rangle |{{C}_{j}}\rangle }$ with quantum circuits by qiskit, where
$\sum\limits_j \langle A| B_j\rangle |C_j \rangle$, $A,B_j,$ and $C_j$
are three quantum states of the same dimension?

Comment: Are $A, B_j$ and $C_j$ Statevectors in Qiskit? How is the question related to Qiskit? Please provide a more elaborate formulation.

Comment: Yes, these are three state vectors of the same dimension, but they are not equal

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

1. You can compute the inner product $\langle A |B_j\rangle$ with `inner()` method of `Statevector`. Just type `A.inner(B)`.
2. You can multiply a `Statevector` with a scalar. So you can write $\langle A |B_j\rangle |C\rangle$ like `A.inner(B)*C`, since the inner product of two states is a scalar.
3. You add can `Statevector` as well, so summing over `j` should be straightforward.
4. Notice though, that a valid `Statevector` must have a norm 1. That is, `S.inner(S)` must be equal 1. Adding or multiplying with a scalar doesn't, in general, preserve the norm. You can check if your `Statevector` is normalized with `is_valid(`) method.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I want, I want to implement each step of the above formula on a quantum computer, instead of the classical computer sharing too many problems for the quantum computer